# Can't seem to center elements in flex (top and bottom)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having big trouble centering two elements in a flex container. What I would like to do is to center one element at the top of the flex container (using flex-start ?) and one element at the bottom of the container (flex-end ?). I have tried several options, but was unable to get what I want. Most of my tries ended in one element in the top left half of the container, and the other one in the bottom right one.....

Please have a look at:  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/phloks/0ccq92ye/4/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div class="flexcontainer1">
    <div class="txt1"> Some text here </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flexcontainer2">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="txt2"> Some more text </div>
      <div class="txt2"> Even more text </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is this at all possible ?

Furthermore: I'm telling the elements to be centered, but it looks like the second line (Even more text) is not centered at all. Or is this just optical ?

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 0):

The `.row` container between the flex container and the flex items is annoying, so get rid of it.

And then,

```css
.flexcontainer1, .flexcontainer2 {
  display: flex;          /* Magic begins        */
  flex-direction: column; /* Vertical layout     */
  align-items: center;    /* Center horizontally */
}
.flexcontainer1 { justify-content: space-around;  }
.flexcontainer2 { justify-content: space-between; }
```

```css
.flexcontainer1, .flexcontainer2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.flexcontainer1 {
  justify-content: space-around;
  height: 250px;
}
.flexcontainer2 {
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 150px;
}
.txt1 {
  font-size: 3.0vw;
}
.txt2 {
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer1">
  <div class="txt1">Some text here</div>
</div>
<div class="flexcontainer2">
  <div class="txt2">Some more text</div>
  <div class="txt2">Even more text</div>
</div>
```